# Magento Custom Table Rates - Blank screen on edit

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I created a new table rates section and whenever I try to save it ( on the website level ), it seems to error. I've been following this tutorial: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method

and have edited these files:

```
Shipping/etc/system.xml
Shipping/etc/config.xml
Shipping/model/carrier/NEWCARRIER.php
Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Shipping/NEWCARRIER.php
```

and also inserted a new table

```
NEWCARRIER
website_id | dest_country_id | dest_region_id | dest_zip | condition_name | condition_value | price | cost
```

Seems to only happen when I try to activate the custom table rate.

================================================================================

The error:

```
An error occurred while saving this configuration: Warning: include(Mage/Shipping/Model/Mysql4/Carrier/NEWCARRIER.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /shop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93 **-- I've Fixed this**
```

New Error:

```
Can't retrieve entity config: shipping/newcarrier
```

Comment: something wrong in your config.xml on model declare, can you post it?

Comment: This config? Shipping/etc/config.xml